# laravel 5 getting extended user info from facebook login

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, laravel-5

i already setup the login with facebook using socialite on my laravel 5 website
but im just getting the basic user data like name, and email
how can i get the user's location(country,city) and birthday?

as of now i have this in my controller to fetch the user's data

```
    class UserRepository {
   public function findByUsernameOrCreate($userData)
    {
        return User::firstOrCreate([
                'name' => $userData->name,
                'email'=> $userData->email
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to specify scopes and fields before redirect

```
Socialite::driver('facebook')->fields([
        'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'gender', 'birthday'
    ])->scopes([
        'email', 'user_birthday'
    ])->redirect();
```

:)